# Force to use DatetimeIndex with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetimeindex

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
df.head()
```

Output

```
id  unplug_hourDateTime
0   2018-09-01 01:00:00+02:00
1   2018-03-01 01:00:00+02:00
2   2018-03-01 01:00:00+02:00
3   2018-04-01 01:00:00+02:00
4   2018-04-01 01:00:00+02:00
```

My objective is to build a [calmap](https://pythonhosted.org/calmap/) graph based on the occurrence of record every day, so I need a dataframe with the index in DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex format.

I wrote the following:

```
df['unplug_Date']=df['unplug_hourDateTime'].map(lambda x : x.date())
df_calmap=df['unplug_Date'].value_counts().to_frame()
df_calmap.head()
```

Output

```
               unplug_Date
2018-09-20   16562
2018-09-13   16288
2018-09-19   16288
2018-09-12   16092
2018-09-27   16074
```

At first glance it looks what I was looking for but if I use the calmap package, and I execute `calmap.calendarplot(df_calmap)` I get the an error, which I supposed is due to the format of the index.

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'year'

How can I force the dataframe to use the index column as DatetimeIndex?
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328858/1008588) interesting answer but I can't understand how to use `df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['b']))` with the already existing index and not with a new column.

Comment: What about `df.index = pd.DateTimeIndex(df.index)`?

Comment: It work, thanks! (I used DatetimeIndex method instead of DateTimeIndex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calmap documentation states that it will default sum per day, so you don't have to change your datetime field to a date field. Just change your unplug_hourDateTime column to a [datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) as follows. My example uses method chaining, which means everything is done in 1 go:

```
df_calmap = (df
    .assign(unplug_hourDateTime=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['unplug_hourDateTime']))
    .groupby('unplug_hourDateTime')
    .size()
    .to_frame('count')
)

calmap.calendarplot(df_calmap['count'])
```

Of course, you can also use Josh Friedlander's nice answer:

```
df.index = pd.DateTimeIndex(df.index)
```